# Installation issue with numba library on python 3

Tags: python, installation, module, pip, numba

I am trying to install numba in python however it gives me this error down below, how would I be able to fix it. I am using a 64 bit windows 10 system and using python 3.9. It gives me a wheel error even though I have installed `wheel` using pip.

CMD Error:

```
  Building wheel for numba (setup.py) ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
command: 'c:\python\python.exe' -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\maste\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4uo3q6pv\\numba_24f4c114cf4a4628ab2eab71e4fa46a4\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\maste\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-4uo3q6pv\\numba_24f4c114cf4a4628ab2eab71e4fa46a4\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d 'C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-wheel-ttxzbc1n'
       cwd: C:\Users\maste\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-4uo3q6pv\numba_24f4c114cf4a4628ab2eab71e4fa46a4\
  Running setup.py clean for numba
  Building wheel for llvmlite (setup.py) ... error
  Running setup.py clean for llvmlite
Failed to build numba llvmlite
Installing collected packages: llvmlite, numba
    Running setup.py install for llvmlite ... error
```

Comment: Please show us more context from the error.

Comment: @idontknow I have updated it hope thats more clear. The whole error list is too long but other than the main ones mentioned above its just copying and creating .py files within associated to numba.

Comment: Can you share pip and python version? `pip -V` `python -V`

Comment: @idontknow pip version is 20.3.3 and python version is 3.9.1

Comment: The [requirements on the pypi page](https://pypi.org/project/numba/) are pretty clear: so far, `numba` only works with **Python < 3.9**. Use the latest Python 3.8 instead.

Answer (score -1):

You can download numba whl file form [here](https://download.lfd.uci.edu/pythonlibs/z4tqcw5k/numba-0.51.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl) for python3.9.

Then use `pip install path/numba-0.51.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl`.

Comment: Do I have to place it in the same file directory as my python files because it says that such directory cant be found

Comment: You can download the whl file to anywhere,for example:`D:/aaa` folder.Then use `pip install D:/aaa/numba-0.51.2-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl`

Comment: I have ran it it still gave me an error. I looked if numba was compatible with python 3.9, the version that I have. It says that numba is only compatible between pthon 3.6-3.8 on github (https://github.com/numba/numba). So I dont think it can work, I will have to use a different version of python.